# Short story about people preparing for a fall of boiling rain

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I believe this was a short story. It seemed to be about a colony of people preparing for the fall of boiling rain. This wasn't the first time it had happened, the people knew to prepare for the rain.

At the end of the story, it is revealed that the people are in fact ants, and it is a human pouring boiling water into an ant nest.